# Reduce number of record types available on record creation

Tags: record-type

I have 7 record types available on the product object. However I wish for only 3 of those record types to be available to a user on creation of a new record. Is there anyway I can do this?

Note that the user must have the ability to be able to edit records of all 7 record types, however they should only be able to create records for 3 of the record types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, edit their profile and remove the four record types they don't need access to. Record Type access does not restrict the ability to edit records (that's the sharing system's job), it simply restricts the ability for a user to create a record of a given record type, and prevents them from changing an existing record to that record type.